# Bootstrap right column dynamic height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to make a layout with a right column with bootstrap. However, I don't know how to do it in order to have a disposition like this.
[image]

I've tried different things but the right column doesn't have the size of the content of the left. I'm on bootstrap 3.
This is what've tried but has you can see  the right column doesn't have the height of the 3 left content. 
[bootply](https://www.bootply.com/LFCdHsJij1)

Can you help me?

Comment: bootstrap 3 or 4? and where's the code you've tried? Post that please.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you are wanting to do is something like:

```
<div class="row equal-height-cols">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            <div class="col-md-12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

```
.equal-height-cols{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: stretch;
}
```

You will need to pus some content in there to see it in action, but that should set you up with what you are looking for.

*edit: misunerstood exact meaning of questions, updated

Comment: doesn't appear to work. OP wants the right column height to match the height of the left column https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owqvzb

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using bootstrap rows/cols, and add flexbox on top. You could do this with bootstrap alone if you used bootstrap 4, since it utilizes `flex` instead of floats for the rows/cols.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  .flex {
    display: flex;
  }
  .wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .red {
    background: red;
  }
  .blue {
    background: blue;
  }
  .yellow {
    background: yellow;
  }
  .green {
    background: green;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="row flex wrap">
        <div class="col-xs-6 red">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 yellow">2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 blue">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 green">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use flexbox, it is the best approach for this, or your can use your right column as a absolute position and make it `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`, providing a max-width size, please see: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Here you have a codepen demo :D

https://codepen.io/johuder33/pen/awYoBo